# What is the function of URLs as "key" names in markup used for a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, hateoas

I just finished reading [REST in Practice](http://amzn.to/1JgUEZj) as my first* introduction to REST APIs. I found the book quite enlightening, but am left with one nagging question, and Google has yet to clear it up. [This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/170695/28071) gets close, but the answers fall short of answering my specific question, which is...

Given some hypertext markup for consumption with a RESTful API, such as [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#basic-concepts) (in JSON-LD):

```json
{
  "http://schema.org/name": "Manu Sporny",
  "http://schema.org/url": { "@id": "http://manu.sporny.org/" },
  "http://schema.org/image": { "@id": "http://manu.sporny.org/images/manu.png" }
}
```

What is the function of the URL/URI/IRI as a "key" name?  (Now I know that JSON-LD--with `@context`--and other markup languages, allow ways to generalize these IRIs-as-keys to be more human friendly, but that doesn't change the nature of the question.)

If I try to break my question down into smaller pieces, I come up with something like this:

- Specifically, what is expected to live at the endpoint represented by that IRI?
- All the discussion talks about disambiguating key names. But how is `http://schema.org/name` less ambiguous than `name`?
- Is there some (theoretical?) centralized repository of key types that developers are expected to reference, so that these key names all point to some more-or-less common definition?

I hope this question makes enough sense to be answerable. I'm still in a bit of a "I don't know enough to ask what I don't know" state on this particular point.

*I, like many, thought I already knew what REST was, and believed that my previous, POST-only CGI scripts were representative of REST APIs...

Answer (score 2):

> what is expected to live at the endpoint represented by that URI?

A *resource* of some kind.  Generally, you can identify the type of resource by examining the mime type.  Often, it's just a web page.

> How is http://schema.org/name less ambiguous than `name`?

It lives specifically at the `http://schema.org/` domain, and the domain itself is unique.  In other words, the domain name provides the disambiguation.

> Is there some (theoretical?) centralized repository of key types that developers are expected to reference, so that these key names all point to some more-or-less common definition?

[ICANN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICANN).

Comment: `A resource of some kind.` -- What kind of resource? A human-readable resource that says "a word or phrase that refers to or that can refer to a specific person"?  Or something machine-readable?  Or...? I guess in other words, does this resource tell a developer how to use the data, or does it tell a program how to use the data?

Comment: A resource should have a content-type. The content type spec tells both the developer and the program how to use the data. For example HTML 5 spec tells a web browser how they should interpret a html document, which ultimately leads to a browser drawing a html page (badly in the case of IE 6 :-P)

Answer (score -1):

> What is the function of the URL/URI/IRI as a "key" name?

The answer can be found in **[RFC 5988 (Chapter 5.3. Relation Type)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-5.3)**:

```
Note that extension relation types are REQUIRED to be absolute URIs...
```

Simply put, the "keys" you are referring to are called "relations" and in order to be uniquely identified, you can either use any of the **[standardized ones](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml)** (like self, author, stylesheet, etc) or you can introduce custom ones, in which case you need to namespace (prefix) them in such a way that noone else creates the same named relation that means something else. This is done by using a relation name in a form of an absolute URI, as mentioned in that RFC document.